# Rotating line using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, line, geometry, rotate

I am attempting to rotate each feature of a line layer around its midpoint, but my code below is not working despite not throwing any errors.

Any suggestions?

This essentially worked in QGIS 2, and I am updating my code to QGIS 3 and am running into this issue.`

```py
myLayers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]

for layer in myLayers:
    name = layer.name()

    if "Line" in name:
        layer.startEditing()

        for f in layer.getFeatures():
            lat = (float(f['endLat']) + float(f['startLat']))/2
            lon = (float(f['endLon']) + float(f['startLon']))/2
            midpoint = QgsPointXY(lon, lat)
            the_geom = f.geometry()
            the_geom.rotate(10, midpoint)

            layer.commitChanges()
            layer.changeGeometry(f.id(), f.geometry())
            layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In QGIS 2, `f.geometry()` returns a reference to the feature's geometry. When you use `rotate`, rotation is applied to the feature's geometry.

In QGIS 3, `f.geometry()` returns a copy of the geometry. Therefore, you have to set explicitly the rotated geometry as the new geometry. So, you need to use `the_geom` instead of `f.geometry()` for the second parameter of `changeGeometry` method.

Try this for the interior `for`:

```py
...
layer.startEditing()

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    ...
    ...
    the_geom = feat.geometry()
    the_geom.rotate(10, midpoint)
    layer.changeGeometry(feat.id(), the_geom)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Thank you!! That works and the explanation for why is very helpful